# Migrate session from active record store to cookie store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

Rails 4 will include encrypted cookie based sessions. We'd like to change to that from active record cookie store. Is there a way to do this without interrupting customers of my app? I don't want to remove all current sessions.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that? From the rails security guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html, you should avoid storing larges objects in cookies. => OK, it's now secure, but you should avoid making large cookies. So, to me, just keep using active record session, even if you use encrypted cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Nathan don't go backwards unless you are worried for you DB performance because of the sessions storage. In that case I suggest Redis or Memcached store for your sessions and not for cookie based.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable, I just did it the other way (for reasons I won't go into, we needed to have them in the database). In the application controller, put a before filter like this:

```
prepend_before_filter :migrate_session

def migrate_session
  # migrating over old sessions
  session_model = YourSessionModel.find_by_session_id(session.id)
  if session_model
    data = session_model.data
    data.each do |key,value|
      session[key] = value
    end
    session_model.destroy
  end
end
```

Everything that goes into the session hash will be persisted in the cookie. After you no longer have any active record sessions left, you can get rid of this code.

Answer (score -1):

There is another problem. I tried to migrate from active record to cookie store and every user now gets "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error. The solution is to clear the cookies but I have to tell it to every user. Many of them will think the site is broken. So this is bad. And if you cannot contact every user, this is extremely bad.